# Get the naviagion-bar Left Button click

Tags: onsen-ui

With OnsenUI 1.0.4 I used this command ons.navigator.getCurrentPage().options.onLeftButtonClick to get the click event(string) for the left button from navigation bar.

In OnsenUI 1.1.x I changed my project to use the ons-toolbar.
How do I get the left button now?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using ng-click or onclick attribute to button tag s.t.

```
<ons-toolbar>
<div class="left"><ons-toolbar-button ng-click="myNavigator.popPage()">Btn</ons-toolbar-button</div>
....
```

Another solution is using addEventListener as usual javascript s.t.

```
<div ng-controller="TbCtrl">
<ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left"><ons-toolbar-button class="btn2">Btn2</ons-toolbar-button></div>
 ....
```

and

```
app.controller("TbCtrl",function($scope){  
    var elem = document.querySelector(".btn2");
    elem.addEventListener("click",function(){ 
      alert("OK"); // Your Code Here
    } ,false);
});
```